# reading file while it is being written

Tags: python, vim, operating-system

Ok. This is weird. I started with an empty file called `foo.txt` and in a python3 interpreter, wrote the following code:

```
>>> import time
>>> f = open('foo.txt', 'r')
>>> while True:
...     print(f.readlines())
...     f.seek(0)
...     time.sleep(5)
...
```

and I started seeing output like this:

```
[]
0
[]
0
```

So far, so good. Then I opened another window, and ran the following:

```
echo "line number 1" >> foo.txt
```

and my output changed to:

```
['line number 1\n']
0
```

Now in the other window, I opened file via `vim` and added one new line such that final state of the file looked like this (I closed vim after that)

```
line number 1
line number 2
```

Strangely enough, I was still seeing the "previous" output in the interpreter

```
['line number 1\n']
0
['line number 1\n']
0
```

I expected to see two lines in the interpreter now, but that was not the case. For some reason, writing file via `echo` was behaving differently from writing file via `vim`.

At that point, I decided to see whether the file descriptor in python is still pointing to the original file.

```
>>> print(f.name)
foo.txt
```

Confused, I decided to check `lsof` output

```
$ lsof | grep foo.txt
python3.6 .... foo.txt~
```

Ah ha! The tilde at the end meant that the open fd is actually now pointing to something else. Running the same experiment on ubuntu (the above was on MacOS), `lsof` had an interesting output

```
$ lsof | grep foo.txt
python3.6 .... temp.txt~ (deleted)
```

So, when the file was opened in `vim`, operating system (?) at that point decided to create a copy of the file for the already opened fd. (But didn't do this when I edited the file via `echo`)

Does anyone know why this happens only for vim, and not for echo?

Comment: I guess that vim does this. It renames `foo.txt` to `foo.txt~` as a backup and then creates a new `foo.txt` with new content. `echo` or more precisely the `>>` operator just appends to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a file (e.g, `foo.txt`) in vim, the editor will typically follow these steps to avoid losing content if something goes wrong while writing to the file:

1. Open a new file with a temporary name in the same directory. (When I tried this, it used a four-digit number as the filename; by way of example, let's call it `1234`.)
2. Write the contents of your buffer to the temporary file `1234`.
3. Check what the permissions and extended attributes were on `foo.txt`.
4. Delete `foo.txt~`, if it exists.
5. Rename `foo.txt` to `foo.txt~`.
6. Rename `1234` to `foo.txt`, and set its permissions and extended attributes to match what it got earlier.
7. Delete `foo.txt~`. (If you `:set backup`, this step is skipped.)

This means that, when you write to a file in vim, the original file gets replaced with a completely new file. The file handle you had open in Python follows the original (now deleted) file.

Appending to a file in the shell using `>>` does not follow any of these steps. It just writes extra data to the end of the existing file, like you'd expect.

Comment: @skgbanga Whoops -- changed my mind halfway through. Fixed. :)

Comment: btw, setting `set backupcopy=yes` will make a copy, but overwrite the original one. 
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupcopy'

Comment: The behavior I describe in my answer is with `'backupcopy'` set -- which it is by default.